# 406 error in the Java code

Tags: java

i am writing java code for calling REST API's .

i am getting 406 error with the following code

```
 public List<BlogBean>  view_blogsbytagXml(String tag,String limit) {
    final String VIEW_BLOGSBYTAG1="api/blogs/tag/"+tag+".xml?limit="+limit+"";

 return webResource.path(VIEW_BLOGSBYTAG1).header(ConfigurationUtil.AUTHENTICATION_HEADER, authentication)
    .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_TYPE).get(new GenericType<List<BlogBean>>(){});
   }
```

The connections are ,
private final WebResource webResource;
         private final String authentication;

```
authentication = ConfigurationUtil.getAuthenticationKey();

    ClientConfig config = new DefaultClientConfig();

    Client client = Client.create(config);

    webResource = client.resource(ConfigurationUtil.BaseURI);
```

i am getting 406 error in the above code

but when i gave the String as

```
    final String VIEW_BLOGSBYTAG="api/blogs/tag/"+tag+".xml";
```

it doesnt show the error for me ..

Comment: a "406 error" sounds like a HTTP error to me, what is the type of webResource? can you paste your imports? i really should downvote for poor post...

Comment: please turn on code formatting in your IDE. This was hardly readable.

Comment: and why on earth does this question have a ruby-on-rails tag?

Comment: @seanizer As i am calling REST API's written in ruby on rails i tagged this post to rubyon rails

Answer (score 5):

Code 406 is [HTTP status](http://www.checkupdown.com/status/E406.html). Server maybe wants send data in other MediaType than MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_TYPE.

Comment: Above comment sounds about right. Looks like the OP is using Jersey. Check the Content Type in the response header.

Comment: how to check the Content type in the response header

Comment: i run the Url api/blogs/tags/sample.xml?limit=2 .. ANd checked the response header i got it as content type is :application/xml; charset=utf-8

Comment: You could try to use TypeMedia.WILDCARD, which accept everything. If you want to know particular type, try to call url in browser with some extension for showing http headers (firefox with firebug)  or in some HTTP client.

Comment: @Aruna Send whole http headers.

Comment: Host localhost:3000
User-Agent Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.2.3) Gecko/20100423 Ubuntu/10.04 (lucid) Firefox/3.6.3
Accept text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language en-us,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding gzip,deflate
Accept-Charset ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
Keep-Alive 115
Connection keep-alive

Comment: I Have triedby modifying MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_TYPE with MediaType.WILDCARD_TYPE . But even i am getting the same error

Comment: It seems, it is not problem with Accept header, try other Accept-* headers (Accept-Charset,Accept-Encoding,Accept-Language,Accept-Ranges). If blog service is running on your server, try to look to its logs.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to [earlier solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3707184/13377558) answer the main culprit for almost all the times 406 error comes is missing this header:
Content-Type:application/json